# Showing that $2^n - 1$ is not a prime number if $n$ isn't a prime number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I'm asked to show that $2^n - 1$ is not a prime number if $n$ is not a prime number. I've managed to prove that if $n$ is even you can rewrite the expression as $n=2k$ and then $2^{2k} - 1 = (2^k - 1)(2^k + 1)$. However the other non prime numbers are stumping me.

Comment: Yes! As a matter of fact it does, since the answer in that question uses proof by contradiction. The contradiction can be used to prove my question.

Comment: $\displaystyle \left(2^a - 1\right) ~| ~\left(2^{ab} - 1\right).$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$S=n^2-1$$ Your question can be rephrased as **If $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is not prime then $S$ can never be prime**

Since $n$ is not prime then $n>2$ Now we can factor $S$ as $(n+1)(n-1)$ Both of $n+1$ and $n-1$ will be greater than $1$

So we see that $S$ has two factors and none of them are equal to $1.$ Hence $S$ atleast has two factors that are not equal to $1$ $$\boxed{\implies\textrm{S is not prime}}$$

Comment: The question text doesn't match the title: what OP is asking is actually $2^n-1$